# Test class in managed package is failing with Internal Salesforce Error: 415122577-6508 (-1655455180) (-1655455180)

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, managed-package, failing-tests, sfdx-error

When Managed package metadata is deployed to a scratch org and tests are run by automated pipeline, one of the test method in a test class is failing with following error **"Internal Salesforce Error: 415122577-6508 (-1655455180) (-1655455180)"**

Current Test class API version is : 52

I already tried to run test class (TestABC) by changing its version to 58, but its still failing.

Note : TestABC class is calling LogABC, TestABCFactory, ABCController classes.

For example :

```
    @isTest
    public with sharing class TestABC{

    } -> Apex api version : 52

    public with sharing class LogABC{
        public static User createLog(){
            
        }
    } -> Apex api version : 46

    public with sharing class TestABCFactory{
        public static User testCreateData(){

        }
    } -> Apex api version : 58

    public with sharing class ABCController{

    } -> Apex api version : 58
```

- Could you please confirm in which scenarios reported error can
  happen?
- What is the best approach to debug this error?

Comment: As a matter of interest, when you say the test classes are "in" a managed package, is this with the package installed (which sounds wrong to me) or with the package's metadata deployed to a namespaced org for development?

Comment: @PhilW Yes its related to the package's metadata deployed to a scratch org for development

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've checked this GACK ID in internal logs and it points to `Java.lang.IllegalStateException: commits are not allowed because someone called setCommitAllowed(false), justification: ApexTestSetupRunner-16983XXXXXXXX`

Salesforce Product team has filed a bug `#W-14312079` to fix this commit call.

ETA for the bug fix is Winter'24, Patch 12 (246.12) (Safe Harbor)

Comment: I will update this thread as I have more inputs

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Could you please confirm if there is any workaround suggested for this?

Comment: Since Test class failure is causing code coverage issue during deployment, could you please confirm the workaround for reported issue? Also is there any way we can track the updates for bug number #W-14312079 ?

Comment: I've reached out internally and still waiting to hear back. Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide update on above?

Comment: Since #W-14312079 is an internal investigation, I will check about creating a known issue that you can use to track the progress. As for the workaround, can you run a global search against the affected objects(being used in the test class), then wait about 5 minutes and retry?

Comment: @VasudevPai Heads up that the 246.12 patch release will hit all production orgs on Nov 2nd. You can monitor the status of your org on https://status.salesforce.com/current/maintenances